# SSIS fastload with indexes disabled on target does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Using SSIS - VS 2008
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)

I am trying to do a bulk update using a staging table. The staging table is an exact schema copy of my destination table. I have read that Indexes can hamper the performance of uploads to a staging table using the fastload option. So I disable the index before the data flow task and rebuild the index after.
 However my SSIS package fails on runtime validation. It seems I cannot do a fastload to the staging table with the indexes disabled. This is the error message I recive: `The query processor is unable to produce a plan because the index 'PK_StagingTable' on table or view 'StagingTable' is disabled."`

If I remove the command where the index is disabled (Step 3 becomes just `truncate table StagingTable`) then the SSIS package works.

The question is should this have worked with the index disabled or is that just bad advice? Is there something missing from the instructions that would allow the insert to work with indexes disabled?

Comment: That's because you have created a clustered key on your table. In the referenced article, dbo.Stage_RowversionExport is a heap with a non-clustered index

Comment: @billinkc 
Good catch there, thx! I'll modify my question to remove the un-necessary fluff, if you want to then post as anwser i'll mark it accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination table (in this case a staging table) you want to use SSIS' fastload option on can have the indexes disabled beforehand, but it will only work if the indexes are non-clustered. In my specific situation, the table I made a schema copy of had a Primary Key, which means it had a clustered-index. I removed the Primary Key on the staging table and created a non-clustered index using the same columns.